# Affordable ERP solutions with Project, BOM , Time

Tags: erp

I am looking in to ERP systems and of course the pricing models are way out of our range - users and then apps.

I have looked at Odoo - but their paid versions are very pricey for the number of users we require.

What ERP solutions out there can support Project Management, BOM, Time, Document Management, CRM .. mobile connections and come with a price tag that is under $3K per year

Comment: [LedgerSMB](https://ledgersmb.org/)  maybe?

Answer (score 2):

We use Vault-ERP for our business. It features time tracking, document management, and much more. Check them out here https://www.vault-erp.com/

Answer (score 1):

How many users do you have? Odoo charges a separate fee for each application used, in addition to user fee, so if you need a variety of applications, that would add a lot to your bill.

If you need a wide range of applications, you can consider [Ragic](https://www.ragic.com). It is a no-code, customizable database, with a library of ready-made templates for most business functions that you can download for FREE. Ragic only charges based on number of users, so extra functions won't add to the bill. Check the [pricing](https://www.ragic.com/intl/en/pricing) information to see if it is more affordable for your number of users.
(Disclosure: I work for Ragic)